# How do I customize what the gvim window shows on top?

Tags: vim, gvim

I don't remember the name of the option. Is not `statusline` and not `guitablabel`. Which one is it? The window shows a `[+]` when `modified` is set, I would like to add more info...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean

```
:set title titlestring=something
```

Comment: Exactly. I couldn't remember that f*cking *obvious* name. Thanks!